# Upload file which contain no extension into wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

Wordpress version:4.7.9.

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

The statement was written into `wp-includes/functions.php`.
Edit a simple file named `test` which contain no any extension.

```
vim test
to upload the file which contain no file extension.
```

Get the error when to upload the file `test`.

```
This file type is not allowed. Please try another.
```

Rename the file `test` into `test.txt`.
And add the following into `wp-includes/functions.php`.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
     $existing_mimes['txt'] = 'application/txt';
     return $existing_mimes;
     }
```

The file `test.txt` can be uploaded successfully.
It is no use to set in the configure file `wp-config.php`.

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

I am using a child of twentyfourteen.

Here is my `/var/www/html//wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/functions.php`

```
<?php
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'twentyfourteen-style'; // This is 'twentyfourteen-style' for the Twenty Fourteen theme.


wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
array( $parent_style ),
wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
?>
```

It can't take any effect.

Comment: so, do you want to use wordpress upload/validation functions? or your target is to just upload file?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I can't upload a file which contain no extesion,how to upload a file which contain no extension?

Comment: where are you uploading the file?

Comment: Wordpress does not output a error like "This file type is not allowed", i searched for this string exactly, nothing to be found, are you uploading via your media library? Maybe it's an error message outputted by your server instead? But I can't tell for sure, but at least couldn't find that string, that's for sure (latest WP version).

Comment: When i do the same test on my side, i get "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons" though. Guess we have different WP versions installed. Anyway `define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS',true);` should fix your problem, just put it in the functions.php of your theme. (make sure there isn't a security plugin that overrides this value at later stage). And make sure to update WordPress. (when I did test again, I was able to upload file without extension without an error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is not with WordPress's backend but it's frontend validation. The uploader is handled by [Plupload](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Options#filters.mime_types) and by default, WordPress is only checking if you have defined `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` in the uploading progress, without really tweaking the frontend plugin's filter validation with the value. Perhaps a small frontend glitch.

As you can see, WordPress is always rendering the following default settings:

```
var _wpPluploadSettings = {"defaults":{"file_data_name":"async-upload","url":"\/wp-admin\/async-upload.php","filters":{"max_file_size":"268435456b","mime_types":[{"extensions":"jpg,jpeg,jpe,gif,png,bmp,tiff,tif,ico,asf,asx,wmv,wmx,wm,avi,divx,flv,mov,qt,mpeg,mpg,mpe,mp4,m4v,ogv,webm,mkv,3gp,3gpp,3g2,3gp2,txt,asc,c,cc,h,srt,csv,tsv,ics,rtx,css,htm,html,vtt,dfxp,mp3,m4a,m4b,ra,ram,wav,ogg,oga,flac,mid,midi,wma,wax,mka,rtf,js,pdf,class,tar,zip,gz,gzip,rar,7z,psd,xcf,doc,pot,pps,ppt,wri,xla,xls,xlt,xlw,mdb,mpp,docx,docm,dotx,dotm,xlsx,xlsm,xlsb,xltx,xltm,xlam,pptx,pptm,ppsx,ppsm,potx,potm,ppam,sldx,sldm,onetoc,onetoc2,onetmp,onepkg,oxps,xps,odt,odp,ods,odg,odc,odb,odf,wp,wpd,key,numbers,pages"}]},"multipart_params":{"action":"upload-attachment","_wpnonce":"9ee7fbf228"}},"browser":{"mobile":false,"supported":true},"limitExceeded":false};
```

A temporary fix to the problem before they fix it on their end would be hooking in the filters WordPress is calling to generate the frontend settings, `plupload_default_settings`.

Add the filter in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('plupload_default_settings', function ($settings) {
    if (defined('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS') && ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS) {
        unset($settings['filters']['mime_types']);
    }

    return $settings;
});
```

This will allow you to upload your `test` via the uploader. Since WordPress is checking already in the backend, as long as you have defined it in your `wp-config.php` that `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` is `true`, it should be uploaded properly.

Comment: Great answer +1, I took the liberty of fixing an small glitch on your code, there was an extra parenthesis

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks, I typed as I go in SO didn't notice haha :p

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there isn't a security plugin or other plugin that overrides your `define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);` :)

I would suggest first to scan for `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` through your site files and see what pops up.

*Also update to latest version of WordPress if you haven't already, since the error message you are getting is different from the one I get.*

Answer (score 3):

[Chin Leung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066042/upload-file-which-contain-no-extension-into-wordpress/49244257#49244257) answer works quite nicely, the only caveat is that any file extension can be uploaded.

The method below needs `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS` set to false (or simply not set on wp-config or functions.php) and it allows file without extensions and blocks extensions not allowed:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', function ( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['*'] = 'text/plain';
    return $mimes;
});

add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', function ( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes) {
    # If filename doesn't containg a dot '.', allow upload
    if( false === strpos( $filename, '.' ) ) {
        $types['ext'] = '*';
        $types['type'] = 'text/plain';
    }
    return $types;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to paste this into your /functions.php file but in your /wp-config.php file.

Alternatively, you can create MIME's for specific file types by pasting this into your /functions.php file, like you have done.

Comment: It is no use to set in the configure file wp-config.php.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true);`  needs to be in in the bottom of wp-config.php... 

Out of interest, how do you have a file that does not contain a file type?

Comment: It is unnecessary to have a file contain a file type.It is no use to put it in the beginning of the wp-config.php or in the bottom of it.Please try it in your wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code at the head of your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

**Note:** For upload new file in media, go to below URL:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/media-new.php
```

Instead of:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/upload.php
```

Because in `upload.php`, mime type validation is done by Javascript.